# Issues of adding warning or info message in Google Sheets Desktop and Mobile App while a process is running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to show some messages (alert or information) while a backend process is running (5-10 minutes) at Google sheets. The following code is working perfectly fine in Desktop Google Sheets. But it does not work at all in Google Sheets Mobile App. Is there any way (e.g. logger.log) that such messages will work in both Desktop and Google Sheets Mobile app seamlessly?

```
   if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C6' && e.range.getValue() === "Error Correction") {    
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var button = ui.alert("Confirm Your Subject Details!!", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      if (button == ui.Button.OK){
        //ui.alert("Error correction process is running. Please wait!!");
        errorCorrect(); 
      }
   }
```

Comment: Apps Script does not work with the Sheets Mobile App, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any alternative messaging system that works for both Desktop and mobile?

Comment: @JeffGibson That is incorrect. For eg, `onEdit` works.

Comment: U could use a cell (like A1) set-up a text and color RED for instance and at the end of the script reset the cell?